# What changes are being made to the Technician question pool in 2018?

Tags: united-states, license, fcc

On 2018 July 1, the FCC's question pool for the Technician class license will be changing.

Has anyone written up a summary of the updates or made a list of differences from the previous pool? What are the most significant changes I should be aware of when helping prospective hams study for the test?

I found the new question pool at http://www.ncvec.org/page.php?id=369 and it includes some errata notes but as far as I can tell they are edits made from earlier drafts of the **new** pool rather than differences from the old.

Comment: Usually, this type of question is answered on arrl.org. Have you tried there?

Answer (score 2):

There's a decent summary [here](https://blog.hamstudy.org/2018/01/first-look-at-the-2018-element-2-technician-class-question-pool/).

Comment: That link shows the differences between the current pool (January) and the pool before that in 2017. I think the OP wanted the differences between the current pool and the new one that will be released in July.

Comment: There's a new pool once every 4 years. The new pool goes live in July 2018.  So my link is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read far enough down the page. Upvote.

Comment: Yep, link is correct and helpful — I'm only hesitant to mark as the accepted answer since StackExchange encourages "self-contained" answers. [Maybe a mod could link to that guideline?]

Comment: Re: self-contained  Understood.